# In .NET, when implementing an implicit conversion operator, is it possible to access the object being assigned to?

Tags: c#, casting, operators, operator-overloading, implicit-conversion

For example, if I have an object such as:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public MyObject(int initialValue)
    {
        this.InitialValue = initialValue;
        this.CurrentValue = initialValue;
    }

    public int InitialValue { get; set; }

    public int CurrentValue { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MyObject(int someValue)
    {
        MyObject result = new MyObject(someValue);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Would it be possible to, in the implicit cast, keep the initial value if there was one and only update the current value?

The idea would be to do something like this:

```
MyObject test = 4; // Both InitialValue and CurrentValue are now 4.
test = 5; // InitialValue is 4 but CurrentValue is now 5.
```

It's a long shot and I don't think it would be possible but if anyone out there has any brilliant ideas to achieve this I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: No because conversion operators always creates a **new** object (it has not any reference to target object) and assignment operator can't be overridden. What you can do is to sacrifice syntax in favor of a `MyObject.Set(ref MyObject target, int value)` static method (it can be done with an extension method too).

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but I don't think it's possible with an operator like this.  This would likely require a method on the `MyObject` class to update the value of a particular instance, and that method would retain the old value as state in that instance.  (This method could indeed be a setter on a property to make it a little more transparent as well.)

Comment: Thanks, I thought as much but thought I'd ask around in any case.

Answer (score -1):

You can cast without making any assignment. One example of this would be when calling a function:

```
void SomeFunction(MyObject passedValue) { /* ... */ }
```

Could be called via your implicit cast like this:

```
SomeFunction(5);
```

And no assignment ever takes place.

Even when assignments do occur, remember that you assign to **variables**, not to objects. In a sense, the object you're asking for in this case is really the `result` variable.